# How do I abort script execution in firebug?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

If I'm getting an infinite loop and find the error stepping through the code, how do I then stop it so that I can reload the page with fixed code?

Answer (score 1):

A. For recursive infinite loops:

There should always be some variable name that contains the function that is being called recursively, regardless of whether the function is private or global.

To stop the recursion, run a code snippet in the console that sets the variable containing the function to an empty function. So if your code is like this:

```
function doLoop() {
    function privateFunction() {
        privateFunction();
    }
    privateFunction();
}
```

Then your code snippet would be this:

```
privateFunction = function(){}
```

B. For *for*, and *while* loops:

Write a line that sets the exit condition to true. In this case, your code to put in the console could be "i = 6":

```
var n = 5
for (var i = 0; i < n; ){
    var x = 1;
}
```